# No sound in Fedora 35 even though everything looks good

Tags: linux, audio, fedora

I am having sound trouble with my newly updated Fedora 35 setup. I know that rebooting fixes the issue, so it is not a hardware or driver problem. It is just that somehow (one of) the sound system (parts) has stopped or doing something wrong.

The symptoms are quite annoying. Everything is fine: my volume works, players (e.g. Spotify web player) start, I can see the right sources and sinks in the settings. But no sound. Just complete quiet. It doesn't matter which output I choose. And of course volume levels are fine.

I *think* I am using `pipewire` (never heard of it until now), because when I

```
systemctl --user stop pipewire.socket
```

my sinks and sources are gone from the settings.

So, I think it should be as simple as restarting some service, but I tried them all, to no effect.

I remember from the past that sound was tricky in Linux, from the OSS/ALSA days. Then I saw PulseAudio coming along, and now apparently it is Pipewire. I have no firm grasp on how this all fits together though. Because until now this all Just Worked™ until Fedora 35.

So, how does this all fit together, and how can I get my sound working again (without having to reboot)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My laptop sound suddenly stopped while I was downloading a package from the Store.
Found out the Sound Icon had greyed out.

On Youtube, it showed `Audio renderer error. Please restart your computer.`

The problem is caused as all audio drivers are not being recognized by the system.
[Pipewire](https://pipewire.org/) Service handles the audio and video in Fedora 35.
Therefore, by [restarting Pipewire](https://forums.fedoraforum.org/showthread.php?326248-Just-upgraded-pipewire-and-want-to-reload-it-without-rebooting&p=1848601) the problem seems to get resolved rather than restarting the entire system.

For me, `systemctl --user restart pipewire` fixed all the issues instantly.

**Update:**
Previously, I had installed the **[KDE](https://spins.fedoraproject.org/kde/)** spin of Fedora. The solution stated above worked for some days, after that only a restart was the solution.
This made me switch to the **[Gnome](https://getfedora.org/)** version of Fedora. Since then, all issues have been resolved.

*The Gnome version of Fedora is very stable compared to the KDE spinoff.*

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Worked for Fedora 35

Comment: Restarting the services works for me, though `wireplumber` needs a `restart` as well.

Answer (score 1):

Since it seems like you have devices recognized, it is likely that the wireplumber service isn't running - see here: https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Common_F35_bugs#No_sound_after_upgrade

Run `systemctl --user enable --now wireplumber` and you should be all set, no restart needed.

Comment: Nope. Tried enabling, starting stopping wireplumber. Nothing.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and even after `systemctl --user enable --now wireplumber` nothing worked.

But I found [this](https://community.frame.work/t/fedora-35-fixing-pipewire-wireplumber-missing-sinks-targets/10378) and it fixed it for me.

TL;DR: The solution was to modify `/usr/share/wireplumber/main.lua.d/50-alsa-config.lua` and comment out the line :`["api.alsa.use-acp"] = true`